# Piwik: Import historical data via the API shows only last two days in dashboard

Tags: matomo

I've set up a Piwik server for logging. I've also written a script that imports historical data via the [Tracking API](http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/).

In order to set a date in the past, I am using the method call `PiwikTracker->setForceVisitDateTime()`. The date is set correctly in the table `piwik_log_visit`.

However, if I open the dashboard I only see the statistics for the past two days. I also ran `php /var/piwik/misc/cron/archive.php url=http://my.logging.url --force-all-websites --force-all-periods=2678400` (2678400 seconds = 31 Days), but to no avail.

Please note that because of my specific use case I cannot use the [log importer](http://piwik.org/log-analytics/).

My question is: **How can I force piwik to (re-)generate the complete statistics for the past month?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution: I dropped the tables `piwik_archive_numeric_YYYY_MM` and `piwik_archive_blob_YYYY_MM` (where YYYY_MM is the corresponding year/month). After that, the data seems to be regenerated upon the first call.

In the Piwik FAQ Entry "[How do I delete all statistics for a given website, or for all websites?](http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/#faq_73)" it is stated that "*They will automatically be re-created from the Visitor logs when Piwik processes your reports.*". However as I am using this for an importer script, I am not sure how this will affect other/existing data - So use at your own risk!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to re-generate the content by doing this:

I've dropped all `piwik_archive_numeric_YYYY_MM` and `piwik_archive_blob_YYYY_MM` tables and generated the new data with `/usr/bin/php5 /pathToPiwik/misc/cron/archive.php url=http://urlToPiwik --force-all-websites --force-all-periods=94608000`